# Multiple records specifying the values with factories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am using Laravel 9. I want to get multiple records with specific values like:

```php
[
    'name' => 'Jon',
    'Age' => 19,
    'Position' => 'Super admin'
],
[
    'name' => 'James',
    'Age' => 22,
    'Position' => 'Admin'
],
[
    'name' => 'Eva',
    'Age' => 20,
    'Position' => 'User'
]
```

I need to put this in the factory:

```
class AdminLoginFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected $model = Users::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Jon',
            'Age' => 19,
            'Position' => 'Super admin',
            // And here i stop :D
        ];
    }
}
```

Can I only do this with factories and call in seeders like this?

```
Users::factory(1)->create();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want or what issues you are having

Comment: @matiaslauriti how to add first array in Factory and to work fine?

Comment: I will ask again, what issues are you having? Doing `Users::factory()->create();` will already cerate 1.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I want make other row with different name, age and position. 1 row with Jon, other with James and other with Eva. How i can make this only with 1 factory?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this example:

```php
[
    'name' => 'Jon',
    'Age' => 19,
    'Position' => 'Super admin'
],
[
    'name' => 'James',
    'Age' => 22,
    'Position' => 'Admin'
],
[
    'name' => 'Eva',
    'Age' => 20,
    'Position' => 'User'
]
```

I will only take care of `Position`:

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker()->firstName(),
        'Age' => $this->faker()->numberBetween(18, 100),
        'Position' => $this->faker()->randomElement(['Super admin', 'Admin', 'User'])
    ];
}
```

You can read more about [`Faker`](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/) and how to use [factories](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories).

Comment: All good but now make only 1 row and with random position and name. I want 3 rows with THIS names, position and ages.

Comment: Then create a seeder with them defined as normal models => `Users::create([WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE]);`, read the documentation please